# LINQ query with EF Core to find records with matching items from many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm quite new to .NET and EF Core and I'm building a classified listing type application. I want to compare records and find matching wanted/for sale classifieds based on their tags (linked via a many to many relationship in entity framework).

First I'm trying to make sure the user isn't trying to add a duplicate listing. I've spent an ungodly amount of time trying to figure out how to write the query but everything I try ends up with an exception at runtime and I feel like I'm trying the same things over and over.

I thought this query should work but I can't figure out why it doesn't, it builds without any errors but I get an exception at runtime of "Specified filter criteria was invalid":

```
public bool IsDuplicate(Classified classified)
{
    var idSet = classified.ClassifiedTags.Select(ct => ct.Tag.Id).ToHashSet<int>();
    var query = from c in _context.Classified 
                where c.ClassifiedTags.Select(ct => ct.Tag.Id).ToHashSet<int>().SetEquals(idSet) &&
                      c.User == classified.User
                select c;

    // .... return true if a record is found
}
```

The tables have a many to many join set up in EF Core: Classified <-> ClassifiedTag <-> Tag

My ApplicationDbContext looks like this

```
public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public DbSet<Classified> Classified { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClassifiedTag> ClassifiedTags { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<Tag>().ToTable("Tag");
    builder.Entity<ClassifiedTag>().ToTable("ClassifiedTag");

    builder.Entity<ClassifiedTag>()
        .HasKey(ct => new { ct.ClassifiedId, ct.TagId });

    builder.Entity<ClassifiedTag>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Classified)
        .WithMany(ct => ct.ClassifiedTags)
        .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.ClassifiedId);

    builder.Entity<ClassifiedTag>()
        .HasOne(t => t.Tag)
        .WithMany(ct => ct.ClassifiedTags)
        .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.TagId);
}
```

My Classified model looks like this:

```
public class Classified
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public List<ClassifiedTag> ClassifiedTags { get; set; }
}

public class ClassifiedTag {
    public Guid ClassifiedId { get; set; }
    public Classified Classified { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

And my Tag model looks like this:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassifiedTag> ClassifiedTags { get; set; }
}
```

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but I'm really stuck for ideas at this point, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you just explain in words what you are trying to achieve? What is this "listing" you refer to? what, in terms of your entity names, is the user trying to add? a `ClassifiedTag`?  Just try to talk me through this story :)

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. The user is trying to add a `Classified` which has a many to many relationship with `Tag` via a `ClassifiedTag` joining table. I'm trying to check that there isn't already an existing `Classified` containing a collection of the same `Tag` records.

Comment: So if the `Classified` has `ClassifiedTag` link, then you want `IsDuplicate` to return true? So what if the `Classified.User` and `Classified.Type` exists but no `ClassifiedTag` links exist, should `IsDuplicate` return `false`?

Answer (score 3):

In your query `ToHashSet<int>()` can't be converted to SQL and an exception occurs.

Comment: *"You can bring all the data to memory"* doesn't sound good, right? That's the whole reason for removing client evaluation in EFC 3.0+.

Comment: That would make sense, I forget what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I've managed to filter the results on the joined table once I've returned all of the records but it seemed a bad idea to load in potentially thousands of records then filter them.

I felt like it'd be better to filter at the query level if possible so I'm only having to return the results I want from the database.

Comment: It would be extremely bad practice to return all your data. Unless you are using some kind of caching system and this only fires either on startup, or on refresh cache request.

Comment: Really annoying that the error message doesn't indicate that `ToHashSet()` is the offender...